# Can multiple BlueprintJS Popovers have the same target? (e.g. one for click and another for hover)

Tags: blueprintjs

Let's say I have a Button component, and I'd like Popover A to appear upon hovering over the Button, and Popover B to appear when clicking on the button. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by nesting the popovers like this:

```
  <Popover content={<div>Hover</div>} interactionKind={PopoverInteractionKind.HOVER}>
    <Popover content={<div>Click</div>} interactionKind={PopoverInteractionKind.CLICK}>
      <Button text="Button with two popovers"/>
    </Popover>
  </Popover>
```

There's a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kpq5w2905).

In the case you don't want the hover popover to appear whenever a user clicks on the button, you can achieve this by switching to `controlled` usage by setting the `isOpen` prop. See the BP docs for more info on this.

Comment: Nice! I went with the below to prevent the hover popover appearing when a user clicks:

        <Popover content={<div>Hover</div>} interactionKind={PopoverInteractionKind.HOVER} disabled={this.state.hideHover}>
          <Popover
            content={<div>Click</div>}
            interactionKind={PopoverInteractionKind.CLICK}
            onOpening={() => this.setState({ hideHover: true })}
            onClosing={() => this.setState({ hideHover: false })}
          >
            <Button text="Button with two popovers"/>
          </Popover>
        </Popover>